# Express polynomial in terms of elemetary symmetric functions

Tags: symmetric-polynomials

I'm working independently through the textbook *Algebra* by Cohn and have reached the section on elementary symmetric functions. I thought I had understood them but am confused by this question:

Express $\Sigma x_1^3 x_2 x_3$ in terms of elementary symmetric functions.

My answer: $e_3(e_1^2-2e_2)$

Book's answer: $e_3(e_1^2-2e_2)-e_4e_1$

Where does $e_4$ come from? As there are only three indeterminates in the question, I don't understand why I need to use $e_4$ at all?

My approach to solving the question was to write out $\Sigma x_1^3 x_2 x_3$ as $x_1^3x_2 x_3+x_1 x_2^3 x_3+x_1 x_2 x_3^3 = x_1x_2x_3(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)$ and then notice that the term in brackets is $e_1^2-2e_2$ and that $x_1x_2x_3 = e_3$